# How to limit arrow function iterations to 10 data?

Tags: javascript, arrow-functions

How to search through 10 datas only?

```
  const filterCategory = (category) => {
    return results.filter(
      result => {
      return result.category === category;
      })
  }
```

Comment: Do you want at most 10 items returned, or only 10 items examined?

Comment: There's not much of a use-case for 10 items examined, but I agree it seems that way as the question is phrased.

Comment: if array is too big you can slice first

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be simplified by the use of ternary operator

```
const filterCategory = (category) => {
  return results.filter(
    (result, index) => {
        return index >= 10 ? false : (result.category === category);
    })
  }
}
```

Comment: shorter isn't simpler.

Answer (score 6):

You can use [`slice()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice) method on the `results` array to get only first 10 items and then you can filter those only like:

```
const filterCategory = (category) => {
  return results.slice(0, 10).filter(result => {
    return result.category === category;
  })
}
```

Comment: This is a better answer.

Answer (score 2):

The second argument for the filter callback is index.

```js
const filterCategory = (category) => {
  return results.filter(
    (result, index) => {
      if (index >= 10) {
        return false;
      }
      return result.category === category;
    })
  }
}
```

Mozilla's docs are a great resource.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter

Comment: Shouldn't `index > 10` be `index >= 10`? Index `0` up to and including `10` is 11 items total.

Comment: Oops. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

If you like to get only ten items as result, you could iterate with [`Array#some`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) and use a short circuit with the new length of the filterd array.

```
const
    filterCategory = (category) => {
        const filtered = [];
        results.some(o => o.category === category && filtered.push(o) === 10);
        return filtered;
    };
```